# R1C1 Notation To Pick Index Range for Index,Match,Match

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot seem to get this line of code working:

```
 For Each errCell In BET_ws.Range("E5:E" & lastrow).Offset(0, 1 + i)
         errCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & cNameAndPath & BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 
         2).Value & "'!R2C3:R1000C200,MATCH(R2C[-1],'" & cNameAndPath & 
         BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value & "'!R2C2:R400C2,0),MATCH(RC3,'" & cNameAndPath 
         & BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value & "'!R1C3:R1C200,0))"
    Next errCell
```

I keep getting an object undefined error. Is it a problem with my R1C1 notation or is it an issue with BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row,2).Value statement? In Column B the tab name needed for my INDEX reference is in the RC2 location. Not sure how to correct the issue. cNameAndPath is defined and is pulling the value I want. Another formula is running in the adjacent range with no problem.

Here is most of the code if it helps:

```
Sub BetConverter()

Dim wbkTarget As Workbook
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim cNameAndPath As Variant
Dim cFileName As String
Dim cFilePath As String
Dim BET_ws As Worksheet
Dim shtTarget As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long 'last row variable
Dim lcol As Long 'last column variable
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim cwbTarget As Workbook
Dim errCell As Range

'kill clunky processes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'delete summary tab if it exists
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BET Consolidated").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'On Error GoTo Errhandler

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Macro")).Name = "BET Consolidated" 'create new tab

Set BET_ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BET Consolidated")

MsgBox ("Please Select the Bid Entry Tool to be Consolidated in the following File Dialog Box.")

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Bid Entry Tool to be Consolidated")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

MsgBox ("Please Select the MDB for Comparison in the following File Dialog Box.")

cNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the MDB for Comparison")
If cNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set cwbTarget = Workbooks.Open(cNameAndPath)
cFileName = Mid$(cNameAndPath, InStrRev(cNameAndPath, "\") + 1)
cFilePath = Left$(cNameAndPath, InStrRev(cNameAndPath, "\"))

Do While shtTarget Is Nothing
    For Each ws In wbkTarget.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "*H*" Then
            Set shtTarget = ws
        End If
    Next ws
Loop

lrow = shtTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

With shtTarget.Range("K2:K" & lrow)
    BET_ws.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

With shtTarget.Range("J2:J" & lrow)
BET_ws.Range("B1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

With shtTarget.Range("O2:O" & lrow)
BET_ws.Range("C1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

With shtTarget.Range("P2:P" & lrow)
BET_ws.Range("D1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

i = 0

For Each ws In wbkTarget.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*H*" Then
        Set shtTarget = ws
        lastrow = shtTarget.Cells(shtTarget.Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row

        With shtTarget.Range("AA1:AA" & lastrow)
            BET_ws.Range(Range("D1").Offset(0, 1 + i).Address).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
        End With

        For Each errCell In BET_ws.Range("E5:E" & lastrow).Offset(0, 1 + i)
        errCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & cNameAndPath & BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value & "'!R2C3:R1000C200,MATCH(R2C[-1],'" & cNameAndPath & BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value & "'!R2C2:R400C2,0),MATCH(RC3,'" & cNameAndPath & BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value & "'!R1C3:R1C200,0))"
        Next errCell

        For Each errCell In BET_ws.Range("F5:F" & lastrow).Offset(0, 1 + i)
        errCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""MATCH"",""DOES NOT MATCH"")"
        Next errCell

        i = i + 3
    End If
Next ws
```

Also tried like this:

```
For Each errCell In BET_ws.Range("E5:E" & lastrow).Offset(0, 1 + i)
        tName = BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value
        errCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & cFilePath & "[" & cFileName & "]" & tName & "'!R2C3:R1000C200,MATCH(R2C[-1],'" & cFilePath & "[" & cFileName & "]" & tName & "'!R2C2:R400C2,0),MATCH(RC3,'" & cFilePath & "[" & cFileName & "]" & tName & "'!R1C3:R1C200,0))"
Next errCell
```

Comment: I have also tried the formula like this which is also still not working.

Comment: For Each errCell In BET_ws.Range("E5:E" & lastrow).Offset(0, 1 + i)
        tName = BET_ws.Cells(errCell.Row, 2).Value
        errCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & cFilePath & "[" & cFileName & "]" & tName & "'!R2C3:R1000C200,MATCH(R2C[-1],'" & cFilePath & "[" & cFileName & "]" & tName & "'!R2C2:R400C2,0),MATCH(RC3,'" & cFilePath & "[" & cFileName & "]" & tName & "'!R1C3:R1C200,0))"
        Next errCell